# Table Viewer length Increases automatically under Section

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I am newbie for the SWT and layouts. I have a Composite A inside that I have Section called "Table Contens" inside that i have another composite "Composite B" inside that I am using Table Viewer which uses `TableColumnLayout`.

All the composite and sections uses Grid layout and
   `GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false);`

My problem is,First time the table will contains 5 rows, So the table size arranges accordingly.If i select another file it will be populated with 10 rows and comes with scrollable.
  When i go to another tab and come back to this table viewer tab it refreshes the layout and the height of the viewer adjust for the 10 rows.

If I give height and width manually it is working `GridData objectivesectiondata=new GridData(670,150);`

But I want the table to resize based on the screen but i need to restrict the height of it.

I know i need to do something with the layout .But I dont know how to do it?
I am in need of this very much.Any Advice ?

THanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `GridData` `heightHint` value, something like:

```java
GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false); 

gridData.heightHint = 150;
```